# flowchart diagram in HTML/CSS positioning?

Tags: jquery, html, css, xhtml, flowchart

I am trying to make a flow chart with HTML and CSS but its proving very hard with the amount of divs that im using for the lines boxes sub boxes and answers.

Here is my Jsfiddle, whats the best way to create this flow chart and position them?

This is what i have tried so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/xyQPT/7/

Could jquery be used to position the divs? or even connect them with an arrow?

Comment: You can't style a `<ul>`? It appears you're going in that direction anyways... You could also use jQuery or something to convert a `<ul>` (or some other format) in to an aesthetically-pleasing format.

Comment: UL? can ul position the LIs individually? whats easier.. creating divs and css is a nightmare.

Comment: How about [mxGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/mxgraph.html) or [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/)?

Comment: @BradChristie, its going to be a diagram within a page of a website.

Comment: So it needs to be SEO friendly.

Comment: So keep the meaningful data on the page then when a client is visiting use javascript and hide the text but make it visually appealing. There's nothing to say you can't have both back-end data and an attractive front-end for human-consumption.

Comment: rapheal looks good but struggling to use it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a UL for your child items, then simply use a background-image and offset the text to the width of background image.  This will give the appearance of being connected.

Comment: isnt there an automated tool online. I would have just done it in photoshop and saved the image/

Comment: its a nightmare to position 30 divs!! plus 10 "lines" and "arrows"

Comment: It is not a nightmare if you use a CSS class;  you could accomplish what you are trying to do in under 5 classes I would guess.